# New input field in store information section

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom-field

I need new data field in store information section, like I show in image below.

I tried [this tutorial](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/10/add-new-field-to-store-view.html), but it does not work.

[image: store information field]

Comment: Check magento log file for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the system.xml

/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
For this create a basic module

app/etc/modules/Arunendra_Pratap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Pratap>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
          </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Arunendra/Pratap/etc/config.xml - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arunendra_Pratap>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Arunendra_Pratap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/etc/local/Arunendra/Pratap/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
    <general>
        <groups>
            <store_information>
                 <fields>
                <custom_field translate="label">
                            <label>Your custom label</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom_field>
                 </fields>
            </store_information>
        </groups>
    </general>    
    </sections>
</config>
```

Finally get the date from below code.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/custom_field');
```

Comment: `{{config path="general/store_information/custom_field"}}` in a static block doesn't seem to display the value. Any solution?